# Adjusting Y position of Elements for all Iphone screen size using AutoLayout

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout, ios-autolayout, xcode7.3

I am using an Image view which is placed on top of parent view. Color of parent viewis changed. i want my design to look same on all iphone sceen sizes in portait. top tabel is positioned accuratly as it should be in the center. but I am having issue with my Logo as you can see in screen shots Logo is at perfect place in only iphone 5.5 inch. what constraint i should set to position my logo as same point (lets say S in "YAS" should be touhcing the hair of girl as in Iphone 5.5) for all devices ?
i have applied constaints but its not working please guide me

This is wahtI am getting in previw
[image]
These are my Constraints
[image]
This is my Xib
[image]
  I tried differecnt values for multiplier but nothing happened
[image]

image View is in Scale to fill mode

Comment: upload demo project with one view controller with this configuration or upload images

Comment: @Dinesh is it because of this image ?

Comment: @Lion images are uploaded kindly guide me which other images are you talking abut

Comment: no i want to try this from my xcode. so i am asking about real images not screen shot of storyboard. If possible then make one demo with one VC and upload it if possible

Comment: where can i upload it in zip file format ? and i am using Xib not story board

Comment: @UmairAfzal Oh i got it wrong. I thought you were talking about horizontal alignment of logo wrt to image. Rather it seems the question is about vertical alignment.

Comment: @Dinesh yes i want to posistion in vertically, Horizontally its perfect

Comment: @Lion [Here](http://public.justcloud.com/eetm3ixxyd.100589448) is my project so can you please try and adjust the constraints  ?

Comment: unable to download..!  You can use dropbox, google drive, github etc for sharing project

Comment: @Lion is the link broken ?

Comment: my browser is blocking this link

Comment: your email address ? i can send the project there

Answer (score 0):

Position your LOGO Horizontallycenter manually and then give TOP , LEADING , TRAILING and aspect ration constraint . When your view's width will increase these constraints will increase height of your Logo. 
Also set your ImageView(Logo) View -> Mode to  Bottom (in Attribute Inspector).

Comment: i did not get it !! I am asking about my Logo YAS

Comment: i did that but result is same i gave TOP , LEADING , TRAILING constraint With respect to main view

Comment: TOP , LEADING , TRAILING and ASPECT RATION (this is important). dont give any height and bottom constarint.

Comment: these are the constraint i applied                                                              Image View.centerX = centerX         ,,                                                         trailing = Image View.trailing + 224    ,,  Image View.top = top + 150 ,, Image View.leading = leading + 224 ,,                                                                        aspect = 105:34

Comment: Yes, i am seeing. dont give any center constraint, just give 4 constraint that i am telling.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112380/discussion-between-dharmendra-chaudhary-and-umair-afzal).

Comment: This the not the perfect solution , this is approximate.
if you want to keep that logo at the desired location, why dont you get this stick in the bottom image itself using Photoshop.

Comment: [here](http://public.justcloud.com/eetm3ixxyd.100589448) is the link to my project so any one can please adjust the constraints for me ? i have inclueded the required GUI image as well

Comment: http://www.filetolink.com/a798d7a866   Here is your project after setting constraints